# $T_{i,j}$ is invertible and $\{ T_{i,j} \}_{i,j=1}^{n}$ is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $V$ a vectorial space over $\mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose that $\mathcal{B}=\{ v_1,v_2,\ldots , v_n \}$ is a basis. For each $i,j$ such that $1 \leq i$, $j \leq n$ it is define the operator $T_{i,j}: V \to V$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ as
$$T_{i,j}(v_k)=\begin{cases} v_k & si \ k \neq i\\
 v_i+v_j & si \ k=i
 \end{cases}$$
Prove that each $T_{i,j}$ is invertible and that $\{ T_{i,j} \}_{i,j=1}^{n}$ is a basis for the operator space of $V:$
$$\mathcal{L}(V)=\{ A: V \to V \mid \text{A is a lineal operator} \} .$$

To prove that each $T_{i,j}$ are invertibles it is sufficient to prove that
$$Ker(T_{i,j})=\{0\}.$$

Then, let $x\in Ker(T_{i,j})$ then $T_{i,j}(x)=0$. Since $T_{i,j}: V \to V$ then it is posible to represent $x$ as
$$x=a_{1}v_{1}+\dots+a_{i}v_{i}+\dots a_{n}v_{n}$$
hence
$$T_{i,j}(x)=T_{i,j}(a_{1}v_{1}+\dots+a_{i}v_{i}+\dots a_{n}v_{n})=0,$$
since $T_{i,j}$ are lineal then
$$T_{i,j}(a_{1}v_{1}+\dotsc+a_{i}v_{i}+\dots a_{n}v_{n})=a_{1}T_{i,j}(v_{1})+\dots a_{i}T_{i,j}(v_{i})+\dots+a_{n}T_{i,j}(v_{n})=$$
$$a_{1}v_{1}+\dots+a_{i}(v_{i}+v_{j})+\dots a_{n}v_{n}=a_{1}v_{1}+\dots+a_{i}v_{i}+\dots+v_{j}(a_{i}+a_{j})+\dots a_{n}v_{n}=0 $$
Since $\mathcal{B}=\{ v_1,v_2,\ldots , v_n \}$ is a basis then $a_{k}=0$ $\forall k$ and we can conclude that $x=0$ and then $Kert(T_{i,j})=\{0\}$ hence $T_{i,j}$ son invertibles.

It this correct? I got lost with the second statement. How can I prove that $\{ T_{i,j} \}_{i,j=1}^{n}$ is a basis?

Any idea?